# save the activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a button clicking on which I created an activity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ContactsActivity.class));
        }
```

as a result free memory decreases

I want save the activity and when click the button to start my  activity (stored),

this should help reduce memory leaks

how do I implement it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html. Have a look at activity lifecycle. Also go through the activity stack. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html. You need to go through the links and you might find a solution yourself.

Comment: I understand for to destroy the activity I should to step back

Comment: I have a bottom panel with buttons, clicking on the button I can call many times the exact same activity

Comment: Suppose you have Activity A and B. On Button click you navigate to B from A. Activity A goes to background. It is not destroyed. It's on Activity Stack. Activity B is in Foreground. You click Back Button. Activity B goes to background and Activity A comes to foreground. So activity is not destroyed. OnCreate will only be called one time for each lifetime of the Activity.

Comment: Oh. Good. You want to clear the activity on top of the stack, then the solution in the link works. Your title says save the activity. Do you need to save the activity state??.

Comment: I first thought to do activity - "singleton" to cause the same ... but if there is a way to just clean the chain - it is also good